# Obtener valores del mismo indice en distintos array y asignarles valores distintos

Tags: c#, array

Tengo 2 array que son los siguientes:

```
int[] used = {300,525,110}
int[] total = {350,600,115}
```

(Por cierto, el lenguaje es C# por si alguien pregunta.)

Lo que intento lograr es recorrer cada uno de los array y comparar los valores entre si e ir asignándole otros valores, para que quede más claro se trata de traspaso de memoria entre discos duros, por eso `used` y `total` pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

A `used[2]` (osea 110) le quiero restar 50 para agregárselo a `used[0]` quedando así 
en 350 y luego restarle los 60 que quedan de `used[2]` para añadirlos a `used[1]`.

Los índices (o los valores almacenados en los mismos) entran en juego ya que los valores de `used[i]` no pueden ser mayores a los contenidos en `total[i]`.

Hasta lo que he llegado fue muy poco:

```
  public int moveData(int[] xUsed, int[] xTotal)
    {
        foreach(int totalData in xTotal)
        {
            foreach(int usedData in xUsed)
            {
                int auxData = 0;
                while(usedData <= totalData)
                {
                    auxData = usedData - totalData;
                    //usedData. = auxData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Como se puede ver ahí, recorrí los 2 array pero no logro asignarle el dato, en éste caso `auxData`.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto, desde ya, gracias de antemano, si requieren mas parte del código o más detalles solo comenten.

Answer (score 0):

para poder asignarle el valor auxData a tu array xUsed, debes agregar un contador para poder asignarselo al indice correcto de tu array. Te pongo el código de cómo quedaría y al final tendrías que retornar el nuevo array de xUsed.

```
public int moveData(int[] xUsed, int[] xTotal)
{
    foreach(int totalData in xTotal)
    {
        int cont = 0;
        foreach(int usedData in xUsed)
        {
            int auxData = 0;
            while(usedData <= totalData)
            {
               auxData = usedData - totalData;
               xUsed[cont] = auxData;
            }
            cont += 1;
        }
    }
    return xUsed;
}
```